# How to express B-spline basis function in matrix format

Tags: matrices

Can someone help me with the following Question?

I am not sure if B-spline/NURBS can express as basic function in matrix, as,

$$
x(t) = B(t)c
$$
$$
B(t) = [b_1(t) ... b_M(t)] 
$$
in which x(t) is a Dx1 states, B(t) is known temporal B-spline basis functions, each individual basis function is alos D-dimensional, c is a Mx1 column of coefficients.

If yes, What's the detailed expression of B(t)?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://soliton.ae.gatech.edu/people/jcraig/classes/ae4375/notes/b-splines-04.pdf

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But I still don't know what B(t) consist of. Can you help me?

Comment: unfortunately  i am not working in this field,i do nt know much about B-splines